# Why is the executable not identified even though the containing directory is on the search path?

Tags: path, csh

I have a /usr/sbin on my search path (echo $PATH).

I have my lsof executable in this directory. Why do I get lsof: command not found if I just type lsof on the prompt. I am using csh.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `rehash` since I seem to recall that `csh` uses a hash to find executables. Trying `/usr/sbin/lsof` will also allow you to tell if this is the problem (or may tell you what the problem actually *is*).

Also check the permissions of `lsof` and the `/usr/sbin` directory to make sure they're executable/searchable (although it's unlikely that's a problem).

Failing that, you should probably wait until this question gets nudged across to SU where it belongs :-)

Comment: Can you run _another_ executable in /usr/sbin (without the full path)? In addition, show us what your path actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using csh or tcsh?

What output does this produce?  (If you don't have tcsh, change `tcsh` to `csh` on the first line and comment out the `where` command.)

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

echo 'PATH:'
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | sed 's/^/    /'

echo "% which lsof"
which lsof

echo "% where lsof"
where lsof

ls -lgd /usr/sbin /usr/sbin/lsof
```